# Recalculating and Applying Auto Layout Constraints with Xcode

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have this ViewController that has Auto Layout constraints and for some reason, when I load it with one segue the constraints work and when I load it with another - they don't.

Is there some code I can use that makes sure the constraints I set are applied? Maybe something to recalculate them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Used:

```
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```

if someone runs into this issue.